# What is kctl running on port 22 on a mac?

Tags: ssh, port, mac

I'm trying to free up port 22 for a docker container (that I'll have to run in another port mapping).

I'm running

```
netstat -a | grep 22
```

One of the results I'm getting is:

```
kctl       0      0     22      9 com.apple.netsrc
```

My question is: **What is kctl running on port 22 on a mac?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"kctl" means that is a kernel control socket, not a network socket. This is a separate socket domain for local communication with kernel extensions (see [Apple's developer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/NKEConceptual/control/control.html)). Here's a partial display from my computer:

```
$ netstat -an | grep -B2 kctl | head
Active kernel control sockets
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q   unit     id name
kctl       0      0      1      2 com.apple.nke.sockwall
kctl       0      0      1      5 com.apple.net.necp_control
kctl       0      0      2      5 com.apple.net.necp_control
kctl       0      0      3      5 com.apple.net.necp_control
kctl       0      0      1      6 com.apple.net.netagent
kctl       0      0      2      6 com.apple.net.netagent
kctl       0      0      3      6 com.apple.net.netagent
kctl       0      0      4      6 com.apple.net.netagent
```

Summary: ignore it, it's not relevant to what you're trying to do.